# Understanding order of operations in formula

Tags: order-statistics, precision

Can someone help me understand the order of operations for this formula?

[image]

**Lets say:**

y_estimated = 10, 14, 11 #three different estimates that will be subbed into the formula

y_true= 12

R=3

I think it is supposed to be ((10-12)^2 + (14-12)^2 + (11-12)^2)   > sqrt(ans) > ans/R > ans/y_true > *100

But I'm not really confident in that answer. Any help would be appreciated or if there's a more appropriate place for this question please let me know.

Comment: Your thought is justifiable, because a close reading of the bar for the square root says exactly that--but most likely the square root is actually intended to be taken *after* dividing by $R,$ because (just applying an educated guess) the numerator is likely intended to be a root mean squared error (RMSE).  Does the source of this formula refer anywhere to an RMSE specifically?

Comment: It doesn't. The paper I'm sourcing it from is not very well written and is quite vague about their methods which has been a bit of a burden. Thanks for your help though, your interpretation does make more sense

Comment: And the values that I get from that make more sense than the ones I have been getting with my original interpretation

Comment: "REE" stands for relative estimation error? Or something else?

Comment: Yes @Glen_b you are right- should have included that. Now I just need to find a function in R that does it for me

Comment: `REE <- function(yest,ytrue) sqrt(mean((yest-ytrue)^2))/ytrue` ... ... (I agree with whuber about the R being inside the square root) and have incorporated that; If you want it as a percentage, multiply by 100: $\:$ `REEpct <- function(yest,ytrue) sqrt(mean((yest-ytrue)^2))/ytrue*100`

Comment: `yest <- c(10, 14, 11); ytrue <- 12; REEpct(yest,ytrue)`
`[1] 14.43376`

Comment: Ah thank you! I'm awful at writing functions so this is greatly appreciated!